# Delete big AWS S3 bucket using lifecycle configuration

Tags: amazon-s3

Is there a `how-to` with steps how to delete a big S3 bucket using lifecycle configuration and expiration? I've read docs but can't figure it out

Comment: Where are you stuck?  1. Create a lifecycle policy to delete all objects after 1 day...  2. Wait 1 day...  3. Profit!

Comment: ok i went trough it again and created a rule, let's see if tomorrow it disappears. Thanks